# vue dev tools not working with vue-cli project

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-devtools

I've installed new vue-cli project and when launched locally and opened on localhost:8080 by running

```
npm run serve
```

Vue dev tools stayed inactive. I've read that one needs to initialize Vue instance, in order for it to work, but with vue-cli, app is initialized with `createApp`, but not with Vue instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad. I've accidentally used vue v3 instead of v2. After switching back to 2 version, works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem using vue cli 4.5.3. After an upgrade to 4.5.4 using `vue upgrade` the devtools fired up.